# ARM error Error : L6218E: Undefined symbol scan (referred from computerproject.o)

Tags: assembly, arm

Hello I'm working on a ARM project and my project requires the scan, print, print_char functions. As I was taught I placed the functions after finishing my main function in the form of an EXPORT. However for some reason the functions can't be defined.. I've posted the last section of my main code and the scan, print, print_char functions that I have to use.  Any suggestions would be lovely thank you.

To be specific, the code scans a number and it adds the numbers from 1 to the scanned number. I've made the main function and I have to use to print, scan functions which are put into last sections of the whole code. However, the compiler couldn't use those codes, 
the error code goes like
Error : L6218E: Undefined symbol scan (referred from computerproject.o)

```
AREA computerproject1, CODE
ENTRY
IMPORT scan 
IMPORT print 
IMPORT print_char 

start 

bl scan 
sub r3, r0, #0 
mov r4, #0

again

add r0, r4, r3
sub r3, r3, #1
bne again 
halt 
b halt 
bl print_char 

finish 
mov r0, #0x18
mov r1, #0X20000
add r1, r1, #0x26
SWI 0x123456

END 

AREA computerproject1, CODE 

EXPORT print 
EXPORT scan
EXPORT print_char

print 
stmfd sp!, {r4-r12, lr}
mov r1, r0
mov r0. #4
swi 0x123456
ldmfd sp!, {r4-r12, pc}

scan 
stmfd sp!, {lr}
mov r0, #7
swi 0x123456
ldmfd sp!, {pc}

print_char 
stmfd sp!, {ro, lr}
adr r1, char
strb r0, [r1]
mov r0, #3
swi 0x123456
ldmfd sp!, {r0, pc}
char    DCB 0
```

Comment: " the functions can't be defined.. "  <-  That's not a problem statement.  What do you mean by "can't be defined"?  Hint: there is no such thing. But even if there was such a thing, how do you know they can't be defined?  what makes you believe they can't be defined?  Show more code, show the exact steps that you follow, and show the exact errors that you get.

Comment: for this assembler what does the END directive mean?

Comment: what assembler (the program and thus the assembly language) are you using?  The directives are specific to the program/toolchain not generic so which tools are you using?  Actually I assume less code is adequate to find the problem, we dont need to know what the real function is doing you can chop out those details and get down to just the imports exports and calls...the MINIMAL code to produce the problem.